# Plotly Express bar chart fails with datetime as x axis input

Tags: datetime, plotly, bar-chart

I am desperately trying to find a solution for creating a bar chart with plotly express and datetime values as x axis input. The graph is created but remains empty. Without determining the axis I get a proper graph. Does anyone know a solution for that?

```
import plotly.express as px
print(type(df.index))

fig = px.bar(df, x=df.index, y=df['moneyness'])
fig.show()
```

[image: Screenshot of code and graph]

My dataframe looks like the following:

```
 {'trade_seq': {Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:16:21.725000+0000', tz='UTC'): 3,
  Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:19:23.104000+0000', tz='UTC'): 227,
  Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:23:27.841000+0000', tz='UTC'): 228,
  Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:28:56.438000+0000', tz='UTC'): 183,
  Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:43:06.220000+0000', tz='UTC'): 184},  
....
'moneyness': {Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:16:21.725000+0000', tz='UTC'): -4310.019999999997,
  Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:19:23.104000+0000', tz='UTC'): 761.9400000000023,
  Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:23:27.841000+0000', tz='UTC'): 631.0899999999965,
  Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:28:56.438000+0000', tz='UTC'): -355.2699999999968,
  Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:43:06.220000+0000', tz='UTC'): -646.7200000000012}}
```

Comment: if you're running this in jupyter, what happens if you run `fig.show()` in its own cell versus `fig2.show()` ? do neither of them show up? also what does your `df` look like? can you include a sample in your question using `df.head().to_dict()` ?

Comment: Could you please try to provide us with dummy data to demonstrate your problem? Because we do not know what types of data your columns contain?

Comment: If you see this example : https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/, it works. My first guess is the problem in your data.

Comment: @DerekO: I executed fig.show() in a separate cell, but the graph is still returned empty. Regarding the dataframe, I added an excerpt of the content in the top.